# Creating Tasks inside a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to create Tasks inside a loop like this:

```
List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
for (int id = 0; id < 1000; id++)
{
    tasks.add(new Task<string>((tId) =>
        {
            var taskId = (int)tId;
            var rand = new Random(taskId);
            long sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                sum += rand.Next(1000);
            }
            return string.Format("Task {0}: {1}", taskId, sum) ;
        }, id));
}
```

Then start all tasks like this:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
}
```

Then wait for all to finish:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Then harvest the results:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```

This code is working but I can't control the degree of parallelism (number of max threads).
and I don't know if this practice is right or not?

Comment: Any reason not to use Parallel LINQ for this? It sounds like a more natural approach.

Comment: Why do you need to control the number of threads?

Comment: @JonSkeet May you help me to use P-LINQ!. I'm new with TPL and LINQ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN artical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) describes how to Override the Task Scheduler class to reach that what you want. It is called `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` but a Small advice ... i have worked 2 Months to get a Absolutely save working and Fast solution for my Requirements so you have to investigate a LOT of time in this Task! You should consider about other solutions for that Problem.

Btw you can take a look into the PLinq lib and the [MaxDegreeofParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property. But as a mircosoft developer has told me in a Seminar. Don't do that!. The Task lib and the PLinq lib is Highly optimized in that field so if you change that you will get a gigantic Performance issue

Comment: I fail to understand the algorithm used in your words' casing, sir.

Comment: Ok for you the Short version
"It is possible, but dont do that. It's hard to manage, a Very long task and If your not spent 2 months in that you earn gigant Performance Lags" ;-)

Comment: Feel free to create you own Answer dude an THAN criticize other.

Comment: .. I wasn't criticizing your answer, just your misleading way of typing.